# JS library to put 3D objects inside HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

Once I've stumbled upon a good JS library which allowed to put 3D objects into HTML markup just like normal images and falls back to static images if WebGL is not supported. Now I need this library for my site.

The thing I remember about it is that demo page contained some palm trees and stuff but I can't google it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while, but found it:
http://www.voodoojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the palm trees but try [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison of various WebGL libraries:

http://weblog.benjaminsommer.com/blog/2012/05/13/comparison-of-webgl-framework-apis/